# Cannot set cell alpha in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In one part of my code, i call

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get a number of cells, and then I change their alphas to .35. This works, and the cells look faded.

However, when I scroll the tableview, the cells that move out of the window and then move back are no longer are faded. This happens even though in cellForRowAtIndexPath the alpha for each disabled row is set to .35.

Right before returning the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath I log

```
NSLog(@"%f", cell.alpha);
```

And it returns .35

However, the cell is not faded after scrolling? It appears as if it's alpha magically gets changed back to 1 before being displayed.

Following is my implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath in my Section class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;

if ([self disabled]) 
{
    cell = [SectionedTableViewController tableView:tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellDisabled" style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    cell.alpha = .35;
}
else
{
    cell = [SectionedTableViewController tableView:tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellEnabled" style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    cell.alpha = 1;
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

//if-else block that only sets labels is here omitted

if (cell.textLabel.text == [[cs objectAtIndex:[self c]] type])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

NSLog(@"%f", cell.alpha);

return cell;
```

}

And the view controller that coordinates these sections gets cells from them like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", [[[self sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].alpha);
    return [[[self sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

(and the NSLog is logging appropriate alpha values)

Comment: can you post your implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is probably due to cells being reused in the table view. There is a better way to do this:

You should create an NSMutableDictionary in your view controller and just set keys for the indexes that should be faded.

Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, while you are setting up the cell, set the alpha based on whether or not the index exists as a key in the dictionary.

This solution will work without any weird behavior.

Comment: Even if I give every cell a unique identifier this still occurs.

Comment: Also, if I use this:

        [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.35f]];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.35f]];

in place of changing the alpha, it works, but I can't animate that.

Comment: In the code you posted, you are checking `[self disabled]`. What does this represent? What you are checking is not a function of the cell but a function of your view controller.

Comment: This actually isn't a view controller class. This is a "Section" class, and instances of it are coordinated by SectionedViewController to create a table view. So the disabled flag applies only to the one section of the table that the Section object represents (all cells in one section disabled). But I don't think this class has anything to do with the problem. I will post a little bit more info above.

Comment: It just started working after I cleaned the project -_- thanks for the help anyhow

Answer (score 15):

Adding all subviews to cell's contentView and use the following string in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

`cell.contentView.alpha = {needed_value};`

will works for you.

Comment: Really important detail, make sure to add all your subviews to the contentView's subviews, not the cell's. I spent a good chunk of time trying to figure out why my subviews weren't changing when the cell was.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting alpha value for `cell.contentView` too. Also set alpha in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` as it might not work in iOS 7